# How to properly manage the eigensystem of a matrix depending on parameters?

Tags: matrix, export, eigenvalues

I am interested in studying the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a 'large' matrix (say $1000\times1000$) that depends on two parameters $x$ and $y$.  Let's refer to this matrix as

```
BigMatrix[n_,x_,y_]
```

where $n$ is the size and $x, y$ are the previously mentioned parameters.  I would like to create a 'master' table of `Eigensystem[BigMatrix[1000,x,y]]` for many values of $x,y$ and export it so I don't have to rerun these Eigensystem commands all the time.  I have tried

```
Export["BigTable.mx",Table[Eigensystem[BigMatrix[1000, j/100, k/100]], {j, 
   0, 100, 1}, {k, 0, 100, 1}]];
```

but Mathematica seems to stop working when I leave it running overnight.  Is there a more efficient way?  Or should I be exporting `Eigensystem[BigMatrix[1000,x,y]]` for each value of $x$ and $y$?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You are trying to put 100*100 very large results in a file.  I would think about putting each result in its own file.  That way at least: 1. You'll get a good idea of how long it will take to complete.  2. You can restart it if you run into problems part way through.  3. You reduce the risk of running out of memory.

Comment: Use Put or PutAppend after each eigensystem is calculated.

Comment: Thank you!  I was not aware of the PutAppend command.